# My Azure Web Application has no access to my SQL Azure DB

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-sql-database

It seems that due to the SQL Azure Firewall Rules my Windows Azure has no access to the DB.
Because of this I put one single rule that opens all:

MicrosoftServices IP-Start: 0.0.0.0 IP-End: 255.255.255.255

What now works is:

OK: When I run the Web-App locally inside VS2010 I have access to the remote SQL Azure DB.

NOT OK: But after deployment to Windows Azure there is NO access to the SQL Azure DB from inside the cloud!

Comment: Are the deployment and the sql azure in the same data center or afinity group? are you sure you are using the correct connection string?

Comment: DB is in Region: South Central US
Hosted Service in an Affinity Group in Region: Anywhere in US

Comment: Forgot to mention the connection string. Since it is working from my VS2010 to SQL Azure, it must by OK.

Comment: I´ve moved the Hosted Service to the same Region as Azure DB: South Central US.
No chance, no connection to DB

Comment: @vtortola: since I cannot get it to work in the cloud yet, here comes the connection string: server = tcp:myserver.database.windows.net; database =  AdventureWorks;User ID=Me@myserver;Password=mypw;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for all the time invested (and wasted, sorry).
I don't believe it.
It rememberes me my times with the Pascal compiler on a DEC PDP-11 in the early 80s, see my answer to @Eugenio.

Cause: the whole day I deployed the same old wrong *.cspkg from a subdirectory.
From within which I NEVER accessed the SQL Azure Server!!

The same error on a local machine would have been resolved in 10 minutes by setting one breakpoint and F10ing through the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the Firewall Rules setup, did you check the box for "Allow other windows azure services access to this server"? If so, the firewall rules grid should have a row for "MicrosoftServices"

Comment: That's what I've configured (see above). And to be 100% sure I've done this: MicrosoftServices IP-Start: 0.0.0.0 IP-End: 255.255.255.255

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @Eugenio: that was the problem I faced the whole day. I could neither set breakpoints or debug at all or see my trace/debug-output in the cloud. Exceptions would have happened in the DAL that is an assembly without access to HTML-output. So I threw one exception after the other and deployed a dozen of times during hours. It is so an awful waste of time. It remembered me my times with the Pascal compiler on a DEC PDP-11 in the early 80s. Had to wait five minutes between each debug-iteration. But I’ve finally found the cause. See my own answer below.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. A couple of suggestions: automate your deployment, use diagnostics tracing, use intellitrace. The last 2 should help you identify problems right away. Intellitrace is nicely integrated into VS. Good luck!

Comment: @Eugenio: Thanks for the tip. I see you work for the Patterns & Practice team. But I had a problem that only happened after deploying my web-app to the cloud. We have a meticulously tracing system in place, but where to send the output when we have no access to the physical server? Could you point me to a URL with more debugging information for the live cloud?

Comment: Henry99 - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966484.aspx. Hope it helps.